# Remove everything before last forward-slash (including that slash) in a C char array

Tags: c, text-processing

I have a char array called `arg`. `arg[0]` is the path to a file. I do not know the exact path, so lets just say it's `/path/to/file`. I do not want to know the full path, I just want to know the filename (`file` in this case). So how can I remove everything before the last forward slash (including that slash), resulting in `"file"`, instead of `"/path/to/file"`, or `"alternatefile"`, instead of `"/alternatepath/to/alternatefile"`?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *arg[] = argv;
    // This is where I need code to trim everything before the last forward-slash
    printf("%s\n", arg[0]);
}
```

So I need something like `arg[0] = strtrm(everythingbefore, "/", arg[0]);`

Comment: You mean you have a string array `arg`

Comment: You do know that strings in C are terminated by the special character `'\0'`? Everything after this terminator is not cosidered to be part of the string. Now think how you could use the terminator to "remove" the last few characters of a string.

Comment: You might also want to learn about the [`strrchr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strrchr) function.

Comment: `strtok` is a preferable suggestion, since it would "remove everything before the last forward slash" so to speak

Comment: Oh, I just read the full question, and it really contradicts the title of your question. Do you want to remove from everything *after* or *before* the slash? The [`strrchr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strrchr) function is still a good function to read about, together with [`strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks for pointing that out. I changed the 'after' in the title to 'before'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc > 0) {
        char *base = strrchr(argv[0], '/');
        if (base) {
            base += 1;
        } else {
            base = argv[0];
        }
        printf("%s\n", base);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should check the value of `argc` before using `argv`. The C standard says: _"**If** the value of `argc` is greater than zero, the string pointed to by `argv[0]`
represents the program name; `argv[0][0]` shall be the null character if the
program name is not available from the host environment."_ and _"`argv[argc]` shall be a null pointer."_

Answer (score 2):

Are `libgen.h` and `basename()` (or `dirname.h` and `base_name()`) generally available and vaild for this purpose?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libgen.h>

int main() {

    printf("%s\n", basename("/alternatepath/to/alternatefile"));

    return 0;
}
```

**PRINTS**

```
alternatefile
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple:

```
char full_path[] = "/some/path/to/a/file";

// Get the position of the last slash
char *last_slash = strrchr(full_path, '/');

// `last_slash` now points to the last slash, or is NULL if none is found
// That means `last_slash + 1` points to the first character in the file-name
// (or to the terminator if the path ends with a slash)

// Copy the file-name to another array
char file_name[PATH_MAX];
strcpy(file_name, last_shash + 1);
```

The above code doesn't have any kind of error checking. What checking is needed is hinted at by the comments.

[Shown in action](http://ideone.com/sAZ4N1).

Comment: Dealing with not finding a `/` is not *error checking*, it is basic testing. Furthermore, there is no guarantee that `argv[0]` fits in the `file_name` array, and `strcpy` would invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: @chqrlie On POSIX systems `PATH_MAX` is defined in [`<limits.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/limits.h.html) to be the "[m]aximum number of bytes in a pathname, including the terminating null character." So it should be enough for any file-name. Considering the OP is using forward slashes, I assume a POSIX system is used, like Linux or OSX (now macOS), or an emulated environment like MinGW or Cygwin.

Comment: that's correct, but you can still pass a longer string for `argv[0]` by coining a call to `exec` with appropriate arguments. `argv[0]` is not necessarily the name of the executable, it is whatever the parent process passed to the `exec` system call. This would be a deliberate attack of course.